# Enable APC extension (OVH Hosting) Doctrine2 + Zend

Tags: php, .htaccess, zend-framework, doctrine-orm

I have to say its my first experience with OVH Hosting.

I want to enable the APC extension. I'm currently hosting my app at OVH. 
I tried using the .htaccess file way

```
php5_flag apc.enabled On
```

Also i tried the

```
ini_set('apc.enabled', '1');
```

But it doesn't work. Looks like there's no way to modify the php.ini file.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2):

Unless you can edit `php.ini` directly, I am afraid there's not much you can do. You can always try to contact OVH with the question to enable the APC extension.